# Kerberos SSO Not Working After Updating to Open JDK 8

Tags: java, single-sign-on, kerberos, tomcat8

We are using Kerberos to enable SSO in our webapp, it's working fine with Open JDK 7.
However with the same configuration when we use Open JDK 8 it fails.

1. Server : apache-tomcat-8.5.37
2. JDK  : Open JDK 8
3. Principal Name : HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.TBC.COM

**Jass.conf :**

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=true
    principal="HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.TBC.COM"
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="/home/psleapp0/ats-ui/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/conf/SPNEGO/ats.saifg.keytab"
    storeKey=true
    debug=true
    moduleBanner=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=true
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    debug=true
    moduleBanner=true
    principal="HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.TBC.COM"
    keyTab="/home/psleapp0/ats-ui/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/conf/SPNEGO/ats.saifg.keytab"
    ;
};
~
```

**Krb5.conf:**

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = SAIFG.TBC.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 SAIFG.TBC.COM = {
  kdc = saifg.tbc.com:88
  admin_server = saifg.tbc.com
 }

[domain_realm]
  .saifg.tbc.com = SAIFG.TBC.COM
```

**SPN and encryption types in keytab :**

```
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0 HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.TBC.COM (des-cbc-crc)
   0 HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.TBC.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   0 HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.TBC.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   0 HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.TBC.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   0 HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.TBC.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

**Realm config in Server.xml :**

```
          <Realm
           className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
           debug="99"
           connectionURL="ldaps://SAIFG.TBC.COM:3269"
           authentication="simple"
           referrals="follow"
           connectionName="CN=ServiceId,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Accounts,DC=saifg,DC=TBC,DC=com"
           connectionPassword="ServiceIdPassword"
           userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
           userBase="DC=saifg,DC=TBC,DC=com"
           userSubtree="true"
           roleSearch="(member={0})"
           roleName="cn"
           userRoleName="member"
           roleSubtree="true"
           roleBase="DC=saifg,DC=TBC,DC=com" />
        </Realm>
```

**Error :**

```
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /home/psleapp0/ats-ui/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/conf/SPNEGO/ats.saifg.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): SAIFG.tbc.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ats.saifg.tbc.com
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 63; type: 1
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): SAIFG.tbc.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ats.saifg.tbc.com
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 63; type: 3
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): SAIFG.tbc.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ats.saifg.tbc.com
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 71; type: 23
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): SAIFG.tbc.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ats.saifg.tbc.com
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 87; type: 18
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): SAIFG.tbc.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ats.saifg.tbc.com
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 71; type: 17
Looking for keys for: HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Java config name: /home/psleapp0/ats-ui/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/conf/SPNEGO/krb5.conf
Loaded from Java config
Added key: 17version: 0
Added key: 18version: 0
Added key: 23version: 0
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
Looking for keys for: HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Added key: 17version: 0
Added key: 18version: 0
Added key: 23version: 0
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23.
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=saifg.tbc.com UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=181
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=saifg.tbc.com UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=181
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=204
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 19
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = SAIFG.tbc.COMHTTPats.saifg.tbc.com, s2kparams = null
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 2
         PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 15

>>> KdcAccessibility: remove saifg.tbc.com:88
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11
>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Wed Jul 20 10:35:21 EDT 2022 1658327721000
         suSec is 163481
         error code is 25
         error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
         sname is krbtgt/SAIFG.tbc.COM@SAIFG.tbc.COM
         eData provided.
         msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 19
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = SAIFG.tbc.COMHTTPats.saifg.tbc.com, s2kparams = null
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 23, salt = null, s2kparams = null

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 2
         PA-ENC-TIMESTAMP
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 16

>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 15

KrbAsReqBuilder: PREAUTH FAILED/REQ, re-send AS-REQ
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23.
Looking for keys for: HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Added key: 17version: 0
Added key: 18version: 0
Added key: 23version: 0
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Looking for keys for: HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Added key: 17version: 0
Added key: 18version: 0
Added key: 23version: 0
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 16 23.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=saifg.tbc.com UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=270
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=saifg.tbc.com UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=270
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=98
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=saifg.tbc.com TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=270
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=saifg.tbc.com TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=270
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 1796 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=1796
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove saifg.tbc.com:88
Looking for keys for: HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Added key: 17version: 0
Added key: 18version: 0
Added key: 23version: 0
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbAsRep cons in KrbAsReq.getReply HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com
principal is HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded

Search Subject for SPNEGO ACCEPT cred (<<DEF>>, sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoCredElement)
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 ACCEPT cred (<<DEF>>, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential)
Found KeyTab /home/psleapp0/ats-ui/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/conf/SPNEGO/ats.saifg.keytab for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Found KeyTab /home/psleapp0/ats-ui/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/conf/SPNEGO/ats.saifg.keytab for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Found ticket for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM to go to krbtgt/SAIFG.tbc.COM@SAIFG.tbc.COM expiring on Wed Jul 20 20:35:21 EDT 2022
Entered SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: receiving token = a0 82 08 10 30 82 08 0c a0 30 30 2e 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 06 09 2a 86 48 82 f7 12 01 02 02 06 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02 1e 06 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02 0a a2 82 07 d6 04 82 07 d2 60 82 07 ce 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 01 00 6e 82 07 bd 30 82 07 b9 a0 03 02 01 05 a1 03 02 01 0e a2 07 03 05 00 20 00 00 00 a3 82 05 e5 61 82 05 e1 30 82 05 dd a0 03 02 01 05 a1 0f 1b 0d 53 41 49 46 47 2e 52 42 43 2e 43 4f 4d a2 24 30 22 a0 03 02 01 02 a1 1b 30 19 1b 04 48 54 54 50 1b 11 61 74 73 2e 73 61 69 66 67 2e 72 62 63 2e 63 6f 6d a3 82 05 9d 30 82 05 99 a0 03 02 01 17 a1 03 02 01 05 a2 82 05 8b 04 82 05 87 08 bc 68 25 87 90 72 59 57 8e 8c 6c 7d 71 f0 4f 31 cf 06 87 bb 48 ec 0c e9 e3 96 be 22 58 8d d6 cc 91 ce e1 0e bd e9 5f 37 bf bc b7 9d 56 93 6f 6e 93 01 4c 4c 5e 41 b0 a6 67 2c a0 f5 b0 6e 8e a9 38 1d ad ef c6 d6 6b f7 d2 68 c1 23 51 ad e8 de 78 c0 2c b6 2c 0f d7 75 52 ad c5 dd 62 48 86 c9 3c 2f 87 15 7c 05 cc 3d 55 93 85 db 0e 76 d3 15 9b 75 95 47 f3 78 c3 7b 0a 17 07 ad f6 fa 9f c8 d7 af 5a ae fe 32 ba 58 37 f0 a2 e2 45 9d 2f 1f 5a 1c b0 5c ba 9e ff 2b 7f 52 19 ed 4f 03 55 30 01 bc 8f 48 db c1 73 62 7c c9 39 d2 06 dd 94 f0 dd 65 fd 2d 2c 3b fe 09 9f 2a e5 9c 4c 3f cb 3e 70 23 5c 14 ea 7c d5 50 75 a3 85 5d 0f 5d 07 fe 9e 5d e6 49 5f a7 d9 db 20 56 4c c1 56 93 8d 53 ee 99 7f f5 04 58 f1 ba 3d 28 38 ab bd 6a c5 91 34 d6 20 cb b6 15 e5 a6 85 e5 71 b8 b8 f9 b8 06 a9 c0 27 a2 d6 cd 10 3a 77 e5 9c 65 d0 48 ed da 68 9c 45 1a 37 ba 79 40 b7 0d c7 3b 7d 74 cb 28 d0 19 f8 36 88 47 15 5a fb f5 91 23 73 96 70 d4 57 13 7e a9 c4 c3 c2 16 9e 50 25 33 65 2c f2 2c e4 1d 64 a4 0a 77 19 fa 22 9d 42 a0 d6 6f e1 63 ed 0a 7d 95 37 a9 b6 d3 04 f0 0e 09 04 72 80 12 8b 27 8c 4b 49 d7 70 2a ce 1e 04 e4 99 58 60 02 7c 9b d4 7a 41 41 77 0c 6d 36 f0 d5 0c dd 7c 64 30 a0 12 08 80 e0 c5 bc 8c 1d c8 c0 70 c5 53 09 30 05 4f 40 76 62 93 9f c0 cb 98 d1 4e 7a 0b cd 1d 84 c6 7b 5e 0a f6 c2 49 da 94 84 ee fa 61 da 03 73 63 26 6a 85 90 25 5c 67 34 0d 1b 97 30 ec 9e 14 18 b9 8a 94 31 dc 50 c4 0e b1 09 85 b6 91 3b 5f b8 87 47 92 a5 9b 64 cd a7 0c a5 58 b9 d7 9d c4 57 2d 24 82 a0 ab 37 e8 b2 bc 34 01 6e 1b 0c 1e 84 22 4b 3c 60 f0 84 08 70 e2 65 0a 34 dc 0b 5f fc ae 35 6a 6c fc 88 db 66 d1 25 10 f7 e1 b1 e2 de 0b 66 aa 53 9c a4 e9 2e 48 3b 01 49 92 b7 fe a9 6a 2c 4b d9 1f a0 d3 40 34 51 c1 c6 6d a2 88 31 ae 3e c6 c6 8e e8 3b b6 2b 2d bc 9c 22 14 7c 14 46 f4 78 48 10 be 58 9f a1 52 e2 65 48 2e df 91 65 f9 d9 df a9 8a 67 9e d2 8c 22 71 fc ea f0 9a ce 91 6d 3c bc 79 68 6e fc ef a9 e8 7d cc 42 47 7c e1 48 e9 34 0c b1 b0 7b 3a d8 4f 0b f3 ae 3e 50 2d 87 e4 47 2a 41 b3 06 cb a0 9c b2 4d 08 6f 37 6a e9 0e 25 09 88 46 11 35 cb 15 20 be 67 69 9d 64 86 58 f7 ee 0b 49 08 d2 8b d9 49 16 42 36 d2 99 1b 5f 55 17 e1 f0 38 71 7c 8a 6a 90 14 a9 bf 80 f0 cc c2 da 57 45 f3 00 b7 2c d5 45 f8 0b c9 80 bf 44 eb 71 fe b1 69 89 16 23 d1 51 16 21 1c 0f 35 73 f7 e3 f9 4d 8c 16 29 47 12 25 1f a3 e7 ff 02 02 13 64 dc cc 02 ca f8 a3 b4 7e 1d f2 48 a0 91 46 d9 6f 25 25 76 f7 76 6d 16 3b 49 17 bc 5e 74 3d 8d 45 12 b3 bd 1b e6 c8 f2 95 fa f3 f2 f3 7c 23 0b bb d2 0f 70 d9 4a 77 a0 2a da ed a3 8e 16 a1 e4 68 58 7b fa 47 2c ba 62 c4 22 5c ba 5d 40 ff db 4e 8a 23 0f d3 2b ae ef f8 e1 ae 3a a0 a7 fc 8e c5 1e b1 31 81 4e 69 20 83 df 3f bc 17 4d 60 3b 1d ef 26 6b 06 02 e5 ae 93 cf 07 8a 34 eb d0 34 49 16 51 fe de 0a ce 61 c3 80 6d 9e b4 7a 55 85 4a c9 be cd e5 32 4b a6 24 9d 0a c0 f7 57 e6 3d 09 0e 91 b7 af 6e 23 05 cd 35 76 f5 ff af 26 1b fc be d9 ef 61 06 2a ef da c7 a8 f0 1f 23 3f eb 9a b5 d1 ca 6c 7e 5d f9 d8 00 fe 2a 47 fe f3 f1 c0 80 3c 81 e0 ae 2f 27 7d 0e ce c4 c2 c2 d7 ba 4c 2f 43 7b 79 87 7c d0 00 78 c6 62 67 81 b3 e5 71 ea 88 68 1e db bd fc 09 35 66 bd 1f 39 9d a6 19 27 f8 ff 25 b6 df e4 94 2e 3c a5 93 a0 cb 98 83 85 d8 55 1a 5e 46 e4 70 8f 56 d1 80 76 49 96 84 d5 8e 74 98 6d 15 63 46 23 71 94 98 33 c4 1d 66 48 b3 1c e3 63 fa 52 17 93 49 0c b2 10 1c 8c 48 52 27 3a 21 68 16 a8 d4 6e ad 22 6b 65 c7 4c e4 cb 94 fd 0b 52 f7 9f 37 a9 66 60 4c 92 34 be 80 f3 ea 46 7a 41 a3 d8 bb ba ae 36 e9 d6 3e ff 17 3c f9 b5 73 b0 28 75 7a b4 66 f8 48 f6 77 db 13 0c 24 38 d1 56 02 c4 ac 67 77 38 7c 81 a5 66 ba a3 5b af 31 dd 70 db 47 eb c8 74 42 61 6d b9 15 0c 68 4f 84 99 16 cc c6 98 9f 34 1b 89 5c 03 a7 16 01 23 75 b3 73 e5 63 58 da c9 f9 1b 50 03 8c 46 06 a8 67 2d f3 3a 55 52 82 b3 2c bd 22 14 ac ad 73 23 15 53 b4 12 8b bc d5 2d 0e cf a3 67 d5 ee e1 ff 05 64 9a eb f4 fe 18 97 36 39 e2 31 1c b0 25 3d 52 cd 89 82 a0 3a 6c ac 7b d6 b7 a4 2c b0 6a 69 c8 13 18 cd 37 b3 d8 fc 24 72 9c b4 10 25 9e a7 22 7c 07 96 a2 81 6a 73 e8 22 b6 f5 06 97 f8 d5 2e d4 bd c6 36 82 c1 d4 41 8b b2 2d c3 df e1 33 74 54 d0 67 69 24 e0 98 04 39 fd 4c 96 23 de 50 05 d2 b6 84 2d 01 a7 25 30 e8 ac 98 39 35 3d 5f bc 76 fd a2 f3 01 8e aa c3 0b 30 4d 0f 27 51 65 20 cd 20 39 57 cb 1d 0e b3 f1 2d 7d f7 43 dd ec e1 cc 0c dd 7a 19 c1 e1 16 fa c5 c7 f9 2e d2 7f 0b 7d 7f 17 0f 9a 47 e9 90 4d a4 82 01 b9 30 82 01 b5 a0 03 02 01 17 a2 82 01 ac 04 82 01 a8 d9 88 62 fb 87 8b 9b 40 78 7f ba 69 47 a8 5e 64 2e 46 8d 54 5d b2 77 79 74 7e a1 a9 27 d9 c0 3b 62 7d db 10 71 8c c7 71 bf 08 ef 89 48 94 92 d8 22 5c c9 4c 9b dd 27 46 9c 1e d6 d2 2f 70 7d b9 d5 7e 45 12 c4 4e e0 de 06 a1 eb 5f ac da f0 f4 ef 6f 41 95 95 39 8a 23 d0 fd 21 82 40 86 a6 a5 a7 53 eb f5 f5 fc 21 e7 42 cb 34 75 0d 28 73 6b ac c0 ea 60 92 8e 2b bf 34 1a 1f 88 5d c5 da 01 88 58 ef 35 1b bb 61 3a bc 55 b1 1f 71 61 d3 3c 4c db 47 41 08 48 50 ea 57 bd 6d 28 3a b9 b9 48 78 33 cb 6e a2 a0 57 81 c4 ae c4 83 43 3c a8 d4 d8 12 c3 44 2d 92 bc 8f f0 78 db 24 21 81 6e 61 d7 87 ab bd 27 7d 2b 56 0b b0 a0 8c ed 12 b2 d5 5a 21 d7 b6 76 e3 9f 06 0f e2 58 a9 76 82 99 15 85 01 48 74 50 4d 70 82 88 1e da da e0 2f ab 9b 93 63 51 d2 50 a4 20 16 83 9b ff 23 fb be a7 80 29 6b 72 ec 11 a4 38 5c 79 4e a7 45 be 56 0a bd c3 d5 3a ea 12 53 96 f4 5c 82 c9 09 2d 9e 18 d9 ca 9a 4f d1 f6 b5 1b 01 eb 0b 15 1e 35 d8 7c 49 7e 45 9d 5c 3d 3b 72 b6 28 d3 8f f0 2c 5d 1e cf 3d e7 1a e7 0a 62 6a 05 4a 52 af 3f 70 c8 4c 9e d5 fe 7e de 88 a9 4d 3e 20 23 a4 b9 70 92 6b 72 60 50 15 ca 40 2a 68 96 15 2f bd e7 39 cb 33 01 f3 25 16 0b 51 df f3 ce 76 23 c7 03 b4 40 db c1 09 63 91 cb f9 23 b2 e9 4f da 3a 86 8c 59 77 0c 45 1b 77 9e e2 39 12 e8 b5 0b cf 25 0a 89 60 d8 10 d8 b9 61 d3 c9 ed 14
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mech Token
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: received token of type = SPNEGO NegTokenInit
SpNegoContext: negotiated mechanism = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
Entered Krb5Context.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Looking for keys for: HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Added key: 17version: 0
Added key: 18version: 0
Added key: 23version: 0
Found unsupported keytype (3) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
Found unsupported keytype (1) for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
Using builtin default etypes for permitted_enctypes
default etypes for permitted_enctypes: 18 17 16 23.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
MemoryCache: add 1658327721/005043/C2EC8F07E07485B6743690C4BD0E9C3E/hkalauni@SAIOAK.SAIFG.tbc.COM to hkalauni@SAIOAK.SAIFG.tbc.COM|HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
>>> KrbApReq: authenticate succeed.
Krb5Context setting peerSeqNumber to: 1444206869
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
Krb5Context setting mySeqNumber to: 18364228
>>> Constrained deleg from GSSCaller{UNKNOWN}
Found ticket for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM to go to krbtgt/SAIFG.tbc.COM@SAIFG.tbc.COM expiring on Wed Jul 20 20:35:21 EDT 2022
SPNEGO Negotiated Mechanism = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2 Kerberos V5
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: mechanism wanted = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: negotiated result = ACCEPT_COMPLETE
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: sending token of type = SPNEGO NegTokenTarg
SpNegoToken NegTokenTarg: sending additional token for MS Interop
SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: sending token = a1 81 eb 30 81 e8 a0 03 0a 01 00 a1 0b 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 a2 69 04 67 60 65 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 02 00 6f 56 30 54 a0 03 02 01 05 a1 03 02 01 0f a2 48 30 46 a0 03 02 01 17 a2 3f 04 3d 02 ba fd 53 55 b9 a4 5c c2 63 30 94 aa 57 77 7c 30 03 24 56 ce 19 20 98 21 78 94 5a b0 05 16 37 e2 6c f5 8a 29 7c f5 63 bd 2e 19 b9 8c 4d dd 3d 5e 89 d7 d8 e1 02 bf 77 98 9d ea 21 33 a3 69 04 67 60 65 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 02 00 6f 56 30 54 a0 03 02 01 05 a1 03 02 01 0f a2 48 30 46 a0 03 02 01 17 a2 3f 04 3d 02 ba fd 53 55 b9 a4 5c c2 63 30 94 aa 57 77 7c 30 03 24 56 ce 19 20 98 21 78 94 5a b0 05 16 37 e2 6c f5 8a 29 7c f5 63 bd 2e 19 b9 8c 4d dd 3d 5e 89 d7 d8 e1 02 bf 77 98 9d ea 21 33
Search Subject for Kerberos V5 INIT cred (<<DEF>>, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential)
Found ticket for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM to go to krbtgt/SAIFG.tbc.COM@SAIFG.tbc.COM expiring on Wed Jul 20 20:35:21 EDT 2022
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Found ticket for HTTP/ats.saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM to go to krbtgt/SAIFG.tbc.COM@SAIFG.tbc.COM expiring on Wed Jul 20 20:35:21 EDT 2022
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 16 23.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.HmacSha1Aes256CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=saifg.tbc.com TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=1698
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=saifg.tbc.com TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=1698
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 96 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=96
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove saifg.tbc.com:88
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 13
>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Wed Jul 20 10:35:21 EDT 2022 1658327721000
         suSec is 218484
         error code is 7
         error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database
         sname is ldap/saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
         msgType is 30
>>> Credentials serviceCredsSingle: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 18 17 16 23.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.HmacSha1Aes256CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=saifg.tbc.com TCP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=1698
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=saifg.tbc.com TCP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=1698
>>>DEBUG: TCPClient reading 96 bytes
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=96
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove saifg.tbc.com:88
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 13
>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Wed Jul 20 10:35:21 EDT 2022 1658327721000
         suSec is 222484
         error code is 7
         error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database
         sname is ldap/saifg.tbc.com@SAIFG.tbc.COM
         msgType is 30
KrbException: Server not found in Kerberos database (7)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:70)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(KrbTgsReq.java:226)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.sendAndGetCreds(KrbTgsReq.java:237)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCredsSingle(CredentialsUtil.java:477)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:340)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:314)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(CredentialsUtil.java:169)
        at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Credentials.java:490)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Krb5Context.java:695)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.sasl.LdapSasl.saslBind(LdapSasl.java:125)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:236)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2897)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(LdapCtx.java:2799)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(LdapCtx.java:2772)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.doSearch(LdapCtx.java:1969)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1872)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1797)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:392)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:341)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUserBySearch(JNDIRealm.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1518)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1446)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getPrincipal(JNDIRealm.java:2343)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getPrincipal(JNDIRealm.java:2269)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.authenticate(RealmBase.java:509)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:374)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator$AuthenticateAction.run(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator$AuthenticateAction.run(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:330)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:244)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:140)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.init(TGSRep.java:65)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.TGSRep.<init>(TGSRep.java:60)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:55)
```

Comment: It's not the HTTP SSO that is failing; the logs show that the server is accepting the client's ticket just fine – it's the subsequent connection to the LDAP server for user info retrieval that is failing, because _that too_ is trying to use Kerberos authentication and apparently the LDAP server isn't set up for Kerberos... (although if it's AD, it's always set up for Kerberos, but you're probably using the wrong ldap:// hostname). In other words, the webapp seems to ignoring `authentication="simple"`, but I have no idea why it is ignoring that (Java is way out of my area).